# How to determine the height of a QTabBar

Tags: qt, pyqt, qstyle

I have two different QDockWidgets: One containing some buttons above another main_widget (File explorer), and another containing a QTabWidget.

[image: descr]

**Question: I aim to get the main_widget and the content of the tabs to the same height. How do I do this best?**

Here's the basic layout:

```
# File explorer
file_dock = QDockWidget()
tools_layout = QHBoxLayout()
tools_layout.addWidget(QToolButton(...))
...
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
layout.addLayout(tools_layout)
layout.addWidget(main_widget)
file_dock.setLayout(layout)

# Editor
editor_dock = QDockWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
editortabs = QTabWidget()
...
layout.addWidget(editortabs)
```

**Preliminary solution:**

I can manually tune the spacing between the `tools_layout` and the `main_widget`:

```
layout.setSpacing(2)
```

[image]

However this setting is OS- and Style-dependent.

**Is there a way to calculate the required spacing?**

So far, I've found `sizeHint()`, `minimumSize()` and `totalMinimumSize()` for the `tools_layout`. In a test, they were the same. Which one to use?

That's half of the required information. How do I determine the height of the tabs? Here I've dug into `QStyle.pixelMetric()`, trying

```
style = qapplication().style()
style.pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_TabBarHSpace)
# ! crashes the program
```

Comment: QTabBar *QTabWidget::tabBar() maybe has the required information for you.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that when creating the other QDockWidget, I don't have easy access to the (or a) instance of the QTabWidget, it may even not be created yet. Therefore, I was going for a general statement on the metric.